# Using repelling and attracting forces, how to achieve a grid/square layout of nodes instead of triangular layout

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-equations, visualization

I am trying to figure out what kind of forces, however artificial, would result in a layout of objects in a grid:

[image]

I am trying to use d3 to draw grids - there may be more than one solution. I hypothesize that each black node could attract the local. You could also use an inverse-cubed law for attraction between the green nodes - or only have attraction/repulsion when the degree of freedom is 1.

Comment: try https://www.physics-in-a-nutshell.com/article/4/lattice-basis-and-crystal#primitive-translation-vectors  and https://www.excellup.com/class_12/chemistry_12/SolidState_CrystalLattice.aspx

Comment: There seem to be lots of websites that tell you NaCl has a face centered cubic structure. It is harder to find one that says why. This is the best I found after a quick look. [What makes the NaCl rock salt structure face centred cubic?](https://www.quora.com/What-makes-the-NaCl-rock-salt-structure-face-centred-cubic)

Comment: @mmesser314 good call, will look into that

Comment: more of art then science, since we could create dummy nodes outside the square, and pull outwards too